# Using polar coordintaes to evaluate $\int \int {\sqrt {\frac {1-x^2-y^2} {1+x^2+y^2}} }\ dx \ dy$

Tags: integration

I want evaluate the following integral using polar coordinates.
$$ \int \int {\sqrt  {\frac {1-x^2-y^2} {1+x^2+y^2}} }\ dx \ dy $$ over the positive quadrant of the circle $$x^2+y^2=1$$
I used the substitution $x=r\cos\theta$, $y=r\sin\theta$ and reduced the integral to
$$ \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_{0}^{1} {\sqrt {\frac {1-r^2} {1+r^2}}}r drd\theta$$
Then, I made the substitution $u=r^2$, giving me, $2rdr=du$ and got

$$\int {\sqrt{\frac{1-u}{1+u}}}du$$
I then split the integrand into partial fractions $-1 + {\frac{2}{1+u}}$
How do I now proceed? Can I reduce it to the form $\int \sqrt{x^2-a^2}\ dx$?

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h500441p2812048

Comment: You should try [approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cint%5Csqrt%5Cfrac%7B1-u%7D%7B1%2Bu%7D%24&p=1) for questions like this.

Answer (score 2):

Substitute $u=1+r^2$ and $\mathrm du=2r\,\mathrm dr$, so that

$$\sqrt{\frac{1-r^2}{1+r^2}}r\,\mathrm dr=\sqrt{\frac{2-(1+r^2)}{1+r^2}}r\,\mathrm dr=\frac12\sqrt{\frac{2-u}u}\,\mathrm du$$

Then take $v=\sqrt u$ (so that $v^2=u$) and $2v\,\mathrm dv=\mathrm du$:

$$\frac12\sqrt{\frac{2-u}u}\,\mathrm du=\frac12\sqrt{\frac{2-v^2}{v^2}}(2v\,\mathrm dv)=\sqrt{2-v^2}\,\mathrm dv$$

Comment: Okay, I now get the integral in $\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$ form

Answer (score 1):

Integrate by parts as follows

$$\int {\sqrt{\frac{1-u}{1+u}}}du
= \int {\sqrt{\frac{1-u}{1+u}}}d(1+u)
=\sqrt{1-u^2}+\int \frac{du}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}
$$